# Potentially Dangerous Request.Path (:)

Tags: asp.net

I just updated our website to .NET 4.0 and ever since then I'm getting the following exception.

"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)."

The request URL is: "https://OURDOMAIN:443/:/0"

This request is from many different IPs but the client app seems to always be IE 6.0-8.0.

Why do we keep getting requests for ":/0" and how can we stop this filling our event logs?

**Update:**

It turns out it was a bad javascript file that was creating the erroneous request. Now I just need to figure out what's going awry in the js file.

Comment: Are you asking about the warning or about the request?

Comment: @SLaks: my read is that it's the request, not the exception. He's asking "What's creating this ':/0' request? Also, how can we prevent it?" That's my read, anyway.

Comment: If you look in the IIS logs can you find a referer for these requests?

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I'm trying to figure out what's spawning the request. 

@Martin Smith The logs weren't retaining the referrer but I've turned that on.

Answer (score 1):

The request has to be coming from somewhere.

Do you have an invalid link on your page pointing to it?
Maybe check your Routes in the Global.asax.cs file.

Comment: I've scanned our entire solutions looking for the string ":/0" to no avail. 

There's nothing in the Global.asax.cs.